# Windows LIVE Messenger downloads get stuck on 100%?

Tags: windows, windows-live-messenger

Whenever I receive a file in **Windows LIVE Messenger**,

the files tend to **hang for about a minute once complete** (100%).

---

Details about my setup:

> **Windows 7**, **Live Messenger Build 14**
>
> **AVG Antivirus 9**

---

Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more details about your setup for anyone to be able to give a sensible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually down to Antivirus, particularly one that hasn't fully integrated (or is not fully compatible) with Windows Messenger.

Take a look in the `Options > File Transfer` and untick `Scan files for viruses using` box.

[image]

This is safe, especially if you have an active virus scanner as it will be scanned anyway - this is simply an extra level of protection.

Alternatively, you may want to look in your received files directory - I had this problem a while ago where it would look like it was hung, but the files had completed.

Comment: Thanks Wil! Very helpful answer! 

I'll see if it gets stuck next time! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can download the latest full **Offline Installer** instead (e.g. from Softpedia):

**[Windows Live Messenger 2009 14.0.8089.726](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Chat/Instant-Messaging/Windows-Live-Messenger-9.shtml)**